# google maps не находит место по координатам

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api, google-maps

Нужно найти ближайший адрес по координатам в google maps

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=44.832359,34.337244&key=***
```

Если отправлять координаты каких нибудь мест(соборы, оперы, театры и тп) то все находит, на нужные координаты ответ такой:

```
{
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

Через геокодер тот же результат:

```
var geo = new google.maps.Geocoder;
var geo2 = geo.geocode({

 location: {lat: 44.832359, lng: 34.337244}

}, function(results, status) {console.log(results)});
```

Comment: Так разве они Крым не блокируют? Запад же сказал "Крыма нет!".

Comment: Хз, остальные действия с крымом и картой норм проходят, только с этим траблы

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего крым на самом деле блокируют, придется делать тоже самое, но через яндекс